# Is $\binom{n}{n/2}\sim 2^n?$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> We say $a_n\sim b_n$ if $\lim_n(a_n/b_n)=1$.
>
> Is $$\binom{n}{n/2}\sim 2^n?$$

Actually, we know $n!\sim n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi}$. So
$$\binom{n}{n/2}\sim \frac{n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi}}{(n/2)^{n+1}e^{-n}2\pi}=c2^{n+1}n^{-1/2}?$$

How about the next step?

Comment: Doesn't your computation already show that $\binom{n}{n/2}\sim 2^n$ does *not* hold? The quotient is $\sim c 2 n^{-1/2} \to 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already gotten $\binom{n}{n/2} \sim c2^{n+1} n ^{-1/2}$, we just want to ensure that $c2^{n+1} n ^{-1/2}$ doesn't go to $2^n$. But
$$\frac{c2^{n+1} n ^{-1/2}}{2^n} = 2cn^{-1/2},$$
which approaches $0$. So
$$\binom{n}{n/2} \not \sim 2^n.$$

(Computing $c$, you can rewrite the asympotic as
$$\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt {\pi n}},$$
which you can find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)